# Are there any detailed references for the enriched yoneda lemma?

Tags: ct.category-theory, yoneda-lemma

I am just starting out learning enriched category theory, and I am looking for a reference proof of the Yoneda lemma for categories enriched in a monoidal category.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this detailed enough? http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf

Comment: A nice concise reference is "[Skew-closed categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6522)" by Ross Street.